# Laravel get last insert record from second table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables which is ;

1. feeds
2. notifications

Now, in `feeds` table I have 1 record and in `notifications` table I have 2 records. Like this:

**Feeds table:**

[image]

**Notifications table:**

[image]

Now, I want to get all the data from `feeds` table and only last inserted data from `notifications` table.

So, here is my query:

```
$get_import = DB::table($mysql_db_name . '.feeds')
->leftJoin($mysql_db_name . '.notifications', 'notifications.object_id', '=', 'feeds.id_feed')
->where('feeds.id_project', $token)
->orderBy('feeds.id_feed', 'desc')
->get(['feed_type', 'id_feed', 'feed_name', 'status', 'content', 'running']);
```

Now the problem is above query is getting all the data from `notifications` table but I want last inserted row data. How can I improve the query?

Comment: The `last inserted row` implies an `INSERT`, which is not the query here. Do you mean the latest date instead?

Comment: @PaulT. On `feeds` table I have several feeds and on `notifications` table I have several notifications of that particular feeds. Now I want to show all the feeds and all the notifications of that particular feeds but the notification should be last inserted notification of that particular feeds.

Comment: Ok, but then why are the `notifications`.`created_at` column all have null? ... won't be able to get the `last inserted notification` from those values.

Comment: I am inserting data to that `notifications` table  manually. I think I need to put the date.

Comment: @PaulT. do you have any solutions?

Comment: I'll have to check later tomorrow, it's after midnight in my TZ.